# Задано количество разрядов числа диапазона unsigned long, имеющих значение. Найти все возможные значения чисел

Tags: c, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Задано количество разрядов числа диапазона unsigned long, имеющих значение. Найти все возможные значения чисел.(язык Си)

Нужен код который выводит все значения в диапазоне unsigned long.
Например, если мы ввели 2 результат должен быть таким:

00000000000000000000000000000011

00000000000000000000000000000101

00000000000000000000000000000110

00000000000000000000000000001001

00000000000000000000000000001010 и т.д.

Comment: Создаете переменную типа unsigned long и в цикле с помощью битовых операций ставить необходимые биты в единицу.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1851134/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адаптированное для `unsigned long` решение Dario Sneidermanis из [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation):

```
typedef unsigned long U;
U nbits = sizeof(U) * CHAR_BIT;
U v = (N < nbits) ? ((U)1 << N) - 1 : (U)-1; // set N least-signficant bits
print_bits(v);

U last = N ? -1 ^ (((U)1 << (nbits - N)) - 1) : 0; // set N most-significant bits
while (v != last) {
  U t = v | (v - 1);  // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
  // next  permutations of bits
  v = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctzl(v) + 1));
  print_bits(v);
}
```

[Пример для N=2](https://ideone.com/K1kekz):

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110
...
1001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

По [ссылке с решением сказано](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation): `__builtin_ctz(v)` это встроенная в GNU C функция для x86 процессоров, которая считает количество  нулей в конце ([bsf инструкция](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27using+U+%3D+unsigned+long%3B%0A%0AU+count_trailing_zeros(U+v)+%7B%0A+++return+__builtin_ctzl(v)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.71193866374589,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%271%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:0.8957951999999999,libs:!(),options:%27-Os%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.28806133625411,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)). [Ссылка](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) говорит, что для Microsoft компиляторов, можно
заменить на `_BitScanForward` (та же инструкция) или использовать [один из способов по явному подсчёту нулей](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear). Можно также адаптировать вариант с делением по [Bit Twiddling Hacks ссылке](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation):

```
while (v != last) {
  U t = (v | (v - 1)) + 1;
  v = t | ((((t & -t) / (v & -v)) >> 1) - 1);
  print_bits(v);
}
```

[Результат тот же](https://ideone.com/nvkFCm).

Comment: Ваш ответ уже давно приняли как единственно верный, что вы никак не успокоитесь и ищете у меня какие-то исключительные случаи гипотетических компиляторов? :) Раз он вас до такой степени раздражает, что вы его до сих пор комментируете - нет вопросов, удаляю. Кстати, крайне советую написать Уоррену и выкатить претензии к нему - я написал, откуда взял код.

Comment: @Harry 1- "undefined behavior" определяется Си стандартом, а не "гипотетическим компилятором". Кстати, ваш ответ не работает на реальных компиляторах, к примеру на ideone. 2- ответ был принят после комментария (посмотрите /timeline). Не нужно выдумывать 3- Какое значение принят или нет. Неадекватная реакция на справедливую критику (ответ у вас не работает). Комментарии для этого и предназначены или вы предпочитаете чтобы вам молча минусы ставили — это менее информативно для будущих читателей. Лично я только благодарен, если в моих ответах ошибку кто-нибудь обнаружит: это улучшает сайт.

Comment: `__builtin_ctzl(v)`, конечно же, "определяется стандартом"... Теперь ТС мучается...

Comment: @Harry "undefined behavior" это о вашем ответе, где вы на ширину типа пытаетесь смещение сделать. Использование compiler intrinsic и UB в разных категориях находятся. Если `__builtin_ctzl(v)` не доступен, можно на вариант с делением заменить (или аналогом, который последовательные нули считает). На ссылку с решением нажмите.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все сработало)

Answer (score 1):

"Битовый трюк" который перечисляет битовые комбинации, содержащие только заданное количество единичных битов можно посмотреть [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). То есть функция вида

```
unsigned long next_combination(unsigned long x)
{
  unsigned long u = x & -x;
  unsigned long v = u + x;
  x = v  + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
  return x;
}
```

будет генерировать требуемые комбинации битов в порядке возрастания. Перебор надо начинать с минимальной комбинации, удовлетворяющей заданным требованиям, т.е. с заданным количеством единичных разрядов в самых младших битах. Переполнение при вычислении очередной комбинации означает, что все комбинации перебраны.